# Why not the page is displayed after migration?

Tags: django

I get the following error:

> OperationalError at /admin/newapp/effectivenessfield/
>   no such table: newapp_effectivenessfield

This error is diplayed on the admin page, but not inside the class

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from completeness.models import Project


class ConclusionName(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    conclusion_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class RetrospectiveField(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     baseText = models.TextField(max_length=255)
     comments = models.TextField(max_length=255)
     project = models.ForeignKey(Project)

class ValidityField(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     baseText = models.TextField(max_length=255)
     comments = models.TextField(max_length=255)
     project = models.ForeignKey(Project)

class EffectivenessField(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User)
     baseText = models.TextField(max_length=255)
     comments = models.TextField(max_length=255)
     project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import ConclusionName, RetrospectiveField, ValidityField, EffectivenessField

admin.site.register(ConclusionName)
admin.site.register(RetrospectiveField)
admin.site.register(ValidityField)
admin.site.register(EffectivenessField)
```

Comment: Have you used command ```makemigrations``` before ```migrate``` command?

Comment: It all did: python manage.py makemigrations, python manage.py migrate

Comment: @cagrias Yes I used

Comment: Change the name of Model  then run migration commands:

python manage makemigrations
python manage migrate

Comment: @zeeshan I used sqlite for db. All applications created earlier work, but no new. change the name? newapp?

Comment: @zeeshan Change the name and it works. Thanks

Comment: @Jhmxtp well done :)